# Equivalence relation $a\sim b$ $ \iff a-b\in\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: equivalence-relations

I have this equivalence relation defined on  $\mathbb{Q}$ and $a\sim b$
$ \iff a-b\in\mathbb{Z}$

I know this is an equivalence relation and have proven so already. But how can I prove that for rational numbers $a,b,c$ we have $a\sim b$ $ \iff a+c\sim b+c$?

I was wondering how I could go about proving this? I was thinking to combine the relations since they are obviously related to each other so $a+c\sim b+c \iff a-b\in\mathbb{Z}$, then would I try and prove the 3 criteria? And if so how? Thank you!

Comment: I'd suggest you write out what $  a+c\sim b+c$ means in terms of the definition of $\sim$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Can I just add c to both sides so $a+c\sim b+c \iff (a+c)-(b+c) \in \mathbb{Z} $?

Comment: $\iff a-b\in\mathbb Z \iff a\sim b\;$; that's it!

Comment: ohhhhh, thank you so much, discrete math always gets me and I never see these simple tricks :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a\sim b\iff a-b\in\mathbb Z \iff (a+c)-(b+c) \in \mathbb Z \iff a+c\sim b+c$

Comment: because $(a+c)-(b+c)=a-b,$ as [J.G.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/56861/j-g) noted

Answer (score 0):

For any $c\in\Bbb Q$, we can reason that $$a\sim b\iff\exists k\in\Bbb Z(a-b=k)\iff\exists k\in\Bbb Z((a+c)-(b+c)=k)\iff a+c\sim b+c$$ because $(a+c)-(b+c)=a-b$.